# 2nd monitor not recognized on boot after upgrade to Xubuntu 14.10

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, mac, vga

I'm running Xubuntu 14.10 on a old MacBook Pro with a VGA monitor as second display. The displays were set up with xrandr in autostart as following:

```
/usr/bin/xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP1 --off --output LVDS-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 1920x180 --rotate normal --output HDMI1 --off --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --off
```

It worked fine in 13.04, but after upgrading the 2nd monitor only works until I login, where it shows the login  mask mirrored from the primary display. Then after login it goes into standby, Xubuntu basically no longer sees it in the config from then on.

At the moment I plug the VGA in/out and run my xrandr script again and it works, but this is rather cumbersome.

It's a GT216M GeForce GT 330M and I'm using X.Org driver.

Any advice where my setup could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Having the monitor in standby and not off before pushing the Mac's power button solved the issue.